# Save graphics context in NSGraphicsContext in order to redraw contents of view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsview, drawrect

I am trying to save a graphics context and display it alongside new added drawings. It's not working for me.

I'm doing this in a loop to draw out names on a custom `NSView`:

```
- (void)drawNamesQuarterFinals{

    self.drawStringWithAttributes = [self stringAttributes:0];


    if ([self.arrayWithQuarterFinals count] > 4)
    {
        for (int i = 0;i < 8;i++){
            self.stringToDraw = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.arrayWithQuarterFinals objectAtIndex:i]];
            self.whereToDrawString = [self namePositions:i rowNumber:0];
            [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];

        }

    }

}
```

This is my `drawRect:` method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{

    NSGraphicsContext *currentContext = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];

    [self drawPlayField];

    [self.stringToDraw drawAtPoint:self.whereToDrawString withAttributes:self.drawStringWithAttributes];
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];

    [currentContext restoreGraphicsState];
}
```

As you can see, I use a loop to draw out all the names, but only the last name is displayed in the `NSView`. The others get overwritten every time `drawRect:` is called.

My question: How can I prevent this from happening? As you can see I've tried to add a`NSGraphicsContext` where I want to save my context to be redrawn, but this is not working. 
I might be way off. Point me in the right direction please!

Answer (score 0):

`setNeedsDisplay:` marks the view as dirty and that it needs to be redrawn. This happens on every run loop. So it gets called only once after the loop is done and hence the last stored values of `whereToDrawString` and `stringToDraw` are used. The correct approach would be to mark the view as dirty when `[self.arrayWithQuarterFinals count] > 4` and then loop the `arrayWithQuarterFinals` array inside the `drawRect:` and draw the strings accordingly.